How do I configure Pi-Hole to serve 192.168.0.0/16
Situation: A standard install of Pi-Hole on a VM under Proxmox running on 192.168.1.2.
Versions are Pi-Hole v5.18.2 FTL v5.25.1 Web Interface v5.21, under Ubuntu 22.04.
For the address space 192.168.1.0/24 it works just fine. Neither Proxmox nor the zoneminder machine has a firewall (yet).
However I need Pi-Hole to work for 192.168.50.0/24 as well, but I cannot discover how to do this. Expanding the address space served by Pi-Hole to 192.168.0.0/16 would be another solution. How can I do one or the other?
I have managed to expand the address space my router thinks it is handling to 192.168.0.0/16.
Other strangeness: I can ping all the 192.168.50.* cameras and all the 192.168.1.* cameras and PCs from my Windows laptop at 192.168.50.199, and I can ping that laptop from Ubuntu on 192.168.1.251. However when pinging the cameras from the Ubuntu machine, I get no replies!?!
Someone will want to know why? I have 2 POE cameras that power on as 192.168.50.224 and 192.168.50.225, and I have found no way to change the IP addresses of these cameras, and I can only use them (from Windows) when in the 192.168.50.0/24 space. While PiHole refuses to do DNS for requests from 192.168.50.*, I can't use the internet from the laptop.
Oddly, I can use the WiFi cameras from the 50 space, although they are in 192.168.1.* space, but I can't use the POE cameras if my laptop is in the 192.68.1.* space.
I would like to know why?

Please restrict yourself to a single problem per question. // You talk about subnets, but how do they map to physical network segments?
